# Доступность установленных компонентов программ для всех пользователей ПК

Tags: delphi-7, windows-7, active-directory, delphi-2010

Есть группа компьютеров, связанная собой средствами Active Directory, с возможностью входа с любого ПК от имени своего пользователя. Компоненты программ, установленные из одного профиля, не отображаются при работе в системе от имени любого другого пользователя. При работе в программах Delphi7 и Delphi 2010, установленные компоненты остаются доступными только при входе в систему от имени пользователя, совершившего установку соответствующего компонента. Возможна ли установка компонента с последующим доступом к нему со всех учетных записей?